# Go forth and review please

Tags: support

The recent changes to the [/review](https://serverfault.com/review) system have helped us to clean up SF somewhat thanks everyone for your support.

Despite several people using their full daily allocation of reviews there is one queue where the numbers remain stubbornly high - [review close votes](https://serverfault.com/review/close).

If you have 3k or more reputation please spend a few minutes in [/review/close](https://serverfault.com/review/close) whenever you can to help us get this cleaned up.

Comment: I really wish the time close votes got reset could be different.  Living in UTC-8 means that the close votes reset at 5:00pm.  I don't want to spend time reviewing things during work, though I will occasionally answer some.  I don't want to use all my close votes at the 'beginning' of the day (when I get off work), or else I won't have any tomorrow.

Comment: If you are reside in PDT, that happens at 4PM.

Comment: @mdpc Which will end in a couple weeks.  In any case it is still annoying for me since it resets a few hours before I would prefer it to>  I want to be able to use all my close votes before I go to bed and wake up to a new set.  But I am sure there is no perfect time.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree, we can use more close voting

## BUT...

Please vote wisely, not just to get badges and not just to get rid of the queue.  I just saw a case where someone selected "Do not close" on a 100% word-for-word duplicate question.  (The OP had cross-posted and the dup had been migrated into SF.)

Answer (score 0):

I must point out that the queue will never get to zero. This is because clicking 'Do not close' doesn't remove it from the queue, it just removes it from *your* queue. You can see this by clicking on some of the history links:

https://serverfault.com/review/close/33573

[image: Close vote example]

Which is kinda cool, but points out that a question can be presented to many people before it is fully expunged. The only way to guarantee kick it out, is to cast the 5th vote, or be a mod and vote-to-close.

Comment: 5 (I think ) normal or one moderator Do Not Close will remove all close votes and then remove the question from the close queue.

Comment: @Iain Having watched for that exact behavior, I'm very sure that a mod no-close has no effect on any in-place close-votes. And [this](http://serverfault.com/review/close/9215) review has two mods voting no-close.

Comment: However, the few cases I can see of double-mod no-closes are all very close together so there may be a timing component involved. The vast majority of mod-actions are the final actions.

Comment: My mSO-Fu is weak. I asked in TL and apparently 3 normal or 1 mod DNC vote will remove it from the queue and start the close votes ageing  immediately (rather than requiring 100 views?). I see this in both the links you provide because I can't use the review queue to vote I only have a next button.