# Cap on Question Review?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that I got cut off at 20 close vote reviews today. Not 20 closures, 20 reviews.

Considering that there are still nearly 1000 in my personal close vote queue and [our Mods are asking us to go out and review](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3775/go-forth-and-review-please) and [to vote more](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3706/how-to-deal-with-bad-questions-vote), is this not counter-productive to reducing the outstanding vote queue and increasing vote percentages?

Comment: Don't forget we only get 24 close votes per day, which usually run out right after breakfast.

Comment: And there's days where I only close about 2/3 of the ones I see, so I could review as many as 40 on those days. Which still allows me to contribute something on days when I know I'm too busy to go look for good questions to answer.

Comment: As @ward says there are ways to game the system. I can't see that this has been a problem on SF as we're more focussed on quality rather than the badges. As is often the case problems caused by the size of SO are 'fixed' network wide.

Comment: @Iain In general, I agree, but we *are* having our own cases of people apparently voting w/out much thought, e.g. http://serverfault.com/review/close/9299

Comment: If you are going to ask for help, with the close queue sometimes in excess of several hundred, this low a limit will be a negative in getting the help you all desire and need.  Please consider raising these limits and we will happily help you out and bring our outstanding amounts down to something reasonable.

Comment: @mdpc: We have no control over the number of votes that individuals have - that is determined by SE. All we can do is request that more people get involved. Right now SF has 288 people >3k but only about 30 use he /review->close queue. The queue is (slowly) going down so more people would certainly make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the questions on meta.SO [(example)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152095/require-a-minimum-proportion-of-each-action-review), there are clearly problems with the /Review system and things are being changed all the time.

This answers says [it's now 20 reviews per user per queue per day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233/130540)  I thought there was another question about close votes, but I can't find it now.

When they upped the daily votes to 40 (but with the caveat about question votes) things changed several times as the system was adjusted and it was really hard to find out what was happening *as it happened.*  I think the changes happening with /Review will be just as confusing, so you either have to hang out on meta.SO or just

> bend over and

take it as it comes.  (Couldn't resist...)